# AWS instance limitation and monitoring API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS EC2 instance type limitation are given in their [official site](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2)

The first line `You are limited to running up to 20 On-Demand instances` denotes that we are limited in setting up only 20 instance per region per subscription I know we can increase this by contacting the AWS.

They are subdivided into

```
    Type    Limit
m4.4xlarge  10
m4.10xlarge 5
c4.4xlarge  10 
c4.8xlarge  5   
cg1.4xlarge 2
hi1.4xlarge 2 
and so on
```

- Is `m4.4xlarge` equal to 2 normal instance and `m4.10xlarge` equal to 4 normal instance and so on ?.
- If so if I create 5 `m4.4xlarge` instance I will be able to create only one `cg1.4xlarge` instance ?
- Is there a AWS API to check the current available instance limit? i.e.) I have created 6 `m4.4xlarge` VM and I call the AWS API requesting available m4.10xlarge limit it will give me the available limit subtracting the used `m4.4xlarge` VM

Sorry if I am not clear and also if this question is not related to this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log into your EC2 dashboard, there is a menu item to see your "Limits" it will tell you how many ec2 servers you have used of each size.

AWS gives you a Global limit as well as a server type limit. New accounts get a maximum of 20 servers running at a time.

So if you use all 20 t2.nano, you cannot use any others as you have hit the global limit. 
I have not tried, but if you run 5 m4.4xlarge instances, you should still have 15 remaining global instances remaining to use however you please, as long as you are still within your individual instance type limits.

If you need to check the limits by code, there is a bit of a hack that you can do if you have all of your instances behind load balancers... just make sure you are using the Amazon API and you should be fine.

```
Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancing.AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient client = new Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancing.AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest1);
Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancing.Model.DescribeInstanceHealthRequest request = new Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancing.Model.DescribeInstanceHealthRequest(elbName);
```

You could also look down the line of the Amazon.EC2 library:

```
Amazon.EC2.Model.InstanceCount
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification .

Comment: `global limit` is independent to region per subscription right ?. i.e.)`if i create 20 nano instance in us.east can I still create 20 nano instance in us.west` or `can I only create 20 nano instance as a whole for subscription`?

Comment: Not quite, my wording was a bit misleading, global limit is for each region. so you can have a max of 20 in us.west and another 20 in us.east etc.  What I meant by global was "total of all instance types"

Comment: Thanks mate for clarifying that limit is for region/subscription.